# Retrieve multiple index locations using pandas.Index.get_loc() or something equivalent

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas index:

```
idx = pd.Index(["a", "b", "c"])
```

I would like to jointly return the integer indexes for the values: `["a", "b"]`

What it the command for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`idx.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
>>> idx.get_indexer(['a', 'b'])
array([0, 1])
```

Another example:

```
>>> idx.get_indexer(['a', 'b', 'x'])
array([ 0,  1, -1])
```

Documentation:

> Notice that the return value is an array of locations in `idx` and `x` is marked by `-1`, as it is not in `idx`.